# Chain catching after derailleur change

Tags: chain, derailleur

I am trying to figure out why my chain is catching with each revolution.  You can see it in this short [video](https://youtu.be/TPUEYh2B_H4)

[[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like one link of your chain is stiff and slightly raised causing it to catch the jockey wheel on each rotation. Do you keep your chain well maintained?

Comment: Did you repin the chain or use a quick link to reconnect  the chain?

Comment: *my chain is catching with each revolution* Each revolution of what, exactly?  It's not the wheel/cassette.  It looks more like the derailleur isn't properly adjusted and the chain is trying to shift to the larger cog.

Comment: Can you give us more info about the derailleur change? What was the old one, what is the new one?

Comment: I replaced the chain also.  I used a special link to connect it

Comment: The old one was gone when I got the bike.  I replaced it with the one I just added a picture of

Comment: I will check the new link to see if it is stiff

Comment: It looks like the chain is hitting the small gear on the derailleur.  See pic

Comment: I should add that the derailer is from a road bike. Can you use a road bike derailleur on a mountain bike?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain is constantly catching the derailleur, every few links or so. It's not a stiff link in the chain - unless the chain is made of stiff links. The chain does not look like it riding onto the next largest sprocket either.

The derailleur is the new factor and it looks like the chain is catching in the cage. I'd check the jockey wheels are rotating freely. I'm guessing one jockey wheel is catching at some point in its rotation.

Comment: There could be something stuck to the upper pulley preventing it from engaging the chain,  or the bushing might be so gunked up it resists spinning intermittently. It is that upper pulley though for sure.

Comment: Looking at it again it seems like the whole cage for the derailleur jockey wheels is bent.  I am concerned about snapping it off it I try to straighten it.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Paul re-looking at the pictures yes the chain is exiting the cage at an angle. The hanger may be bent rather than the cage.